# Link tablix in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have 3 tablix in a report where acceptance date is common in all.
Currently it is displaying by splitting date wise.

I want to display all 3 tablix for particular date at a stretch.
I need to display all 3 tablix grouped for one date (summary report).

Consider for 10 days it will display first tablix for 10 days, next tablix for 10 days & next.

But I want to display all 3 tablix for a date at a stretch.then for next date. So on.

Comment: Providing whatever code you got is best in order to achieve specific, more usefull aswers.

Comment: Simply have the SQL for each of the tablix return what you want to display in the tablix.